# how to split large pandas DataFrame over multiple threads/processes?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a dataFrame with about 300K rows and I need to read the dataFrame and for each line I need to do the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   # do something to row['col A'] and row['col B']
   # set value of row['col C'] based on result of the work done to row['col A'] and row['col B'], where row['col C'] is originally empty.
```

What I have so far is splitting the dataFrame to multiple sub-dataFrames by doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df_split = np.array_split(df, 10)

def one_split(sub_df): # where sub_df is a unique sub-dataFrame of the original dataFrame for each thread/process to work on
   for index, row in sub_df.iterrows():
      # step 1: do something to row['col A'] and row['col B']
      # step 2: set value of row['col C'] based on result of step 1
      # step 3 (not implemented yet): copy values of 'col C' in sub_df to 'col C' in the original dataFrame, that is df in this case.

one_split(df_split[0])
```

my goal is:

1. to split the work over 10 threads/processes to speed up execution time
2. each thread/process executes `one_split(df_split(i))` in parallel.
3. implement step 3 in `one_split()`, each thread/process will work on different part of the original dataFrame, so I "think" **race condition** is not a concern here.

Any suggestions please on how I can achieve my goal?

**Edit**
This image is an example of the desired behavior:
[image]

Comment: Instead of iterating over the rows, have you considered using [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)?

Comment: Have you considered [Dask](https://www.dask.org/)?

Comment: I haven't tried `df.apply()` before, but based on the doc I don't think it solves my problem because the work that needs to be done to 'col A' and 'col B' takes a long time, that is why I'm thinking of multi-threading/processing

Comment: @afarrag I will check Dash, but can you please explain how it works briefly? thank you

Comment: @abs8090, have you tried a vectorial code ? If not yet, can you share a reproducible example (_a few rows_) with the matching expected output ?

Comment: I will edit the question and do my best to provide an example

Comment: You say you "need to do something to row['col A'] and row['col B']". As a general statement, not specific to `pandas`, if what you need to is not a very CPU-intensive operation, a multiprocessing approach will only make the code run more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an idea using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Using cpu count of your machine to split the df and feed the chunks into ProcessPoolExecutor. main function is where you do the work which feeds it back and when all chunks are processed it concats results back to a large df.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


processors = os.cpu_count()
df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
batches = np.array_split(df, processors)


def process_data() -> None:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(processors) as executer:
        result = pd.concat(executer.map(main, batches))

    print(result)


def main(batch: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Do stuff here
    return batch


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_data()
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what I need, I will try it now, Thanks you!